# Internet explorer loses DOM changes even when refresh is canceled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have a page with some post data in it (from a previous form submit).
Moreover, I've been changing the DOM in this page (using jQuery).

When I click F5, both FF and Internet Explorer show me a warning about resending the post data. No surprises so far.

But when I choose Cancel in the pop-up, IE loses all changes I made to the DOM! In FF on the other hand what happens is exactly what I expect: nothing.

Is this a known issue with IE?
Is there a good reason for this behavior? (Why would Cancel do anything at all?)
Is it avoidable?

In case people want to see what I mean, this test page should do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#changeColor').click(
                    function(){
                        $('#container').css('background-color', 'blue');
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <p>To see the behaviour that is different in IE versus FF:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Put something in the textbox and press Submit, just to have a post value.</li>
        <li>Press the "Make blue" button.</li>
        <li>Press F5.</li>
        <li>Click Cancel in the popup.</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    <form method="post">
        <input name="test" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <button id="changeColor">Make blue</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably IE does reload the page without sending a request, but the background is not blue in the new page. What does happen in the devtools? Try to put a log statement in your script, I'd bet it is re-executed.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, the script is executed again. And yes, the blue background disappears, because obviously (the cached copy of?) the original page is reloaded. But why?